# What is the derivative of $\sum_{i,j}^n \langle A^{ij}x_i,x_j \rangle$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus

Given different **vectors** $x_1,\dots,x_n$ and $n^2$ **matrices** $A^{11}\dots,A^{nn}$ with $A^{ij}=A^{ji}$, I would like to calculate  the derivative with respect to $x_k$ of

$$\sum_{i,j}^n \langle A^{ij}x_i,x_j \rangle$$

Am I right that this should be $\sum_{i\not= k}\langle A^{ik}x_i,x_k\rangle + 2\langle A^{kk}x_k,x_k\rangle$

Comment: @OliverDiaz so the solution is given by $2\sum_i x_i^TA^{ik}$?

Comment: @OliverDiaz but isn't it a bit weird. For a quadratic form $\langle x, A x\rangle$ the derivative is given by $2Ax$. Here we consider different vectors $x_i$ and look at a similar expression $\langle x_i, A^{ij} x_j\rangle$. Why do we get here a matrix and in the first place a vector

Comment: Oh! I misread your posting, I thought $A_{ij}$ stood for the entries of a matrix. The answer should still be similar since now you have a multi-bilieanr form, that is, for all $x$'s fixed but one, say $x_i$, you have a bilinear form.

Comment: $g(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\sum_{1\leq i,j\leq n}\langle A^{ij}x_i,x_j\rangle$
$$\begin{align}
g(x_1+h_1,\ldots, x_n+h_n)&=\sum_{1\leq i,j\leq n}\langle A^{ij}(x_i + h_i,x_j+h_j\rangle\\
&= g(x) +\sum_{1\leq i,j\leq n}\langle A^{ij} x_i,h_j\rangle + \sum_{1\leq i,j\leq n}\langle A^{ij} h_i,x_j\rangle  + r(h)
\end{align}$$
where $\frac{|r(h)|}{\|h\|}\xrightarrow{h\rightarrow0}0$
where $\|h\|=\|h_1\|+\ldots+\|h_n\|$.

Comment: The derivative $g'(x)$ I($x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ s the linear operator $g'(x)(h_1,\ldots,h_n)=\sum_{1\leq i,j\leq n}\langle A^{ij} x_i,h_j\rangle + \sum_{1\leq i,j\leq n}\langle A^{ij} h_i,x_j\rangle$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $g:(\mathbb{R}^n)^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ as
$$g(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\sum_{1\leq i,j\leq n}\langle A^{ij}x_i,x_j\rangle$$
where $A^{i,j}\in\operatorname{Mat}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$, $1\leq i,j\leq n$. Then
$$\begin{align}
g(x_1+h_1,\ldots, x_n+h_n)&=\sum_{1\leq i,j\leq n}\langle A^{ij}(x_i + h_i,x_j+h_j\rangle\\
&=\sum_{1\leq i,j\leq n}\langle A^{ij}x_i,x_j\rangle + \sum_{1\leq i,j\leq n}\langle A^{ij} x_i,h_j\rangle + \sum_{1\leq i,j\leq n}\langle A^{ij} h_i,x_j\rangle + \sum_{1\leq i,j\leq n}\langle A^{ij} h_i, h_jx\rangle\\
&= g(x) +\sum_{1\leq i,j\leq n}\langle A^{ij} x_i,h_j\rangle + \sum_{1\leq i,j\leq n}\langle A^{ij} h_i,x_j\rangle  + r(h)
\end{align}$$
where $\frac{|r(h)|}{\|h\|}\xrightarrow{h\rightarrow0}0$
where $\|h\|=\|h_1\|+\ldots+\|h_n\|$.
This means that $g'(x)$, $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ is the linear operator
$$\begin{align}
g'(x)[h_1,\ldots,h_n]&= \sum^n_{i=1}\sum^n_{j=1}\langle A^{ij} x_i,h_j\rangle +\sum^n_{i=1}\sum^n_{j=1}\langle A^{ij} h_i,x_j\rangle \\
&=\sum^n_{i=1}\sum^n_{j=1}\langle A^{ij} x_i,h_j\rangle  + \sum^n_{i=1}\sum^n_{j=1}\langle (A^{ij})^*x_j,h_i\rangle \\
&=\sum^n_{i=1}\sum^n_{j=1}\big\langle \big(A^{ij}+(A^{ji})^*\big)x_i,h_j\big\rangle
\end{align}
$$
where, for any matrix $A^*$ is the adjoint of $A$ relative to the inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$.

If $A^{ij}=A^{ji}$ then
$$ \begin{align}
g'(x)[h_1,\ldots,h_n]&=2\sum^n_{i=1}\sum^n_{j=1}\langle \frac{1}{2}(A^{ij}+(A^{ij})^*)x_i,h_j\rangle
\end{align}
$$
The matrix $\frac12(A_{ij}+A^*_{ij})$ are the symetrization of $A^{ij}$ with respect to the inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$.

Comment: May I ask you one additional question. Why is your solution different from @greg ones? It seems you have a double summation while greg only has a sum over $\sum_{i}^n$

Comment: @swissy: Notice that I wrote an expression for the action of the derivative of $g$ at the point $\mathbf{x}=[x_1,\ldots,x_n]\in(\mathbb{R}^n)^n$ on the vector $\mathbf{h}=[h_1,\ldots, h_n]\in(\mathbb{R}^n)^n$; hence the double summation. That is I wrote an expression for $g'(\mathbf{x})\mathbf{h}$.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'm not 100% sure yet, though. If I want to set the derivative (or transpose, i.e. gradient) to zero, would I just drop one sum. The thing which puzzles me a bit is that both $i$ and $j$ appear in $A$. Many thanks for your clarification / patience. I highly appreciate it

Answer (score 3):

$
\def\bbR#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\o{{\large\tt1}}
\def\e{\varepsilon}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}
\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\BR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\p{\partial}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{c}#1\end{array}\right]}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
$Assume the dimensions of the given vectors and matrices to be
$$x_{i}\in\bbR{p},\qquad A_{ij}\in\bbR{p\times p}$$
Let $\e_i\in\bbR{n}$ denote the cartesian basis vectors,
and use the identity matrix $I\in\bbR{p\times p}$ to construct matrix analogs of these basis vectors
$$
E_i = \e_i\otimes I
 \qiq E_j^TE_k = \delta_{jk}I
 \qiq E_k^TE_k = I
$$
The indexed matrices are blocks of a large partitioned matrix, just as the indexed vectors are subvectors of a larger vector
$$\eqalign{
M &= \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n E_iA_{ij}E_j^T = \m{
A_{11}&A_{12}&\ldots&A_{1n} \\
A_{21}&A_{22}&\ldots&A_{2n} \\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots \\
A_{n1}&A_{n2}&\ldots&A_{nn} \\
}\qquad
z = \sum_{i=1}^n E_ix_i = \m{x_1\\x_2\\\vdots\\x_n} \\
}$$
Note that the $\{E_k\}$ basis can also be used to *extract*
blocks from a partitioned matrix, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
A_{k\ell} &= E_k^TME_\ell
 &\qiq A_{k\ell}^T = E_\ell^TM^TE_k \\
x_k &= E_k^Tz &\qiq x_k^T = z^TE_k \\
Mz &= \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n E_iA_{ij}x_j
 &\qiq M^Tz = \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n E_iA_{ji}^Tx_j \\
z^TMz &= \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n x_i^TA_{ij}x_j \\
}$$

Write the objective function using the partitioned matrix.

Then calculate its differential and gradient
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= z^TMz \\
d\phi &= z^T\LR{M+M^T}dz \\
 &= z^T\LR{M+M^T} \BR{E_k\,dx_k} \\
 &= \BR{E_k^T\LR{M+M^T}z}^T {dx_k} \\
\grad{\phi}{x_k}
 &= {E_k^T\LR{M+M^T}z} 
 \;\;\equiv\;\; \sum_{j=1}^n \LR{ A_{kj} + A_{jk}^T } x_j  \\
}$$

Comment: +1 But shouldn't the gradient be transposed, i.e. $\;\,E_k(M^T+M)z\,?\;$

Comment: @lynn It depends on your preferred [layout convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Layout_conventions). But you're point is well taken, normally I write the gradient as a column vector$.\;$

Comment: thanks for you answer. I have one question. It seems that your $\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial x_k}$ differs from @OliverDiaz answer. In his case the we have a double summation where you sum only over $i$. Why this difference or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion this exercise teaches an important lesson. Namely:

Whenever possible try to work without reference to coordinates!

This is used twofold in this exercise. First, by using a coordinate-free definition of the differential and second by using a coordinate-free description of your function $g$.

Let us first review the coordinate-free description of the differential, aka the 3-term expansion:

Let $g: U \subset \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ be a map and $p \in U$. The map $g$ is called differentiable at $p$ if locally around $p$ it can be written as
\begin{equation}
 g(p+h)=g(p)+(Dg)_p(h)+R_g(p,h)
\end{equation}
where $(Dg)_p(h)$ is linear in $h$ and the rest-term $R_g(p,h)$ satisfies $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{||R_g(p,h)||}{||h||}=0$. The linear map $(Dg)_p$ is called the differential of $g$ at $p$.

More specifically, if the map $g$ is real valued, then the differential $(Dg)_p$ is a linear map from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Recall that any real valued linear map can be uniquely written as the inner product with a certain vector. Therefore, there exists a vector $v_p$ so that
\begin{equation}
 (Dg)_p(h)=\langle v_p, h \rangle
\end{equation}
for all $h \in \mathbb{R}^n$. This $v_p$ is just the gradient $\nabla g(p)$ of $g$ at $p$. So this is a coordinate-free description of the gradient!

Let‘s now come to our specific function. The function $g$ can be written as
\begin{equation}
g(x)=\langle Ax, x \rangle,
\end{equation}
where $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is the standard inner product of $\mathbb{R}^n$. By linearity of $A$ and bilinearity of the inner product we get
\begin{align*}
g(p+h) =& \langle A(p+h), p+h \rangle \\
      =& \langle Ap, p\rangle   \\
       &+ \langle Ap , h\rangle \\
     &+ \langle Ah, p\rangle    \\
     &+ \langle Ah , h\rangle    \\
     =& g(p) \\
     &+ \langle Ap,h\rangle + \langle h  , A^\ast p \rangle \\
      &+ \langle Ah, h\rangle \\
                =& g(p) \\
     &+ \langle (A+A^\ast)p,h\rangle  \\
      &+ \langle Ah, h\rangle,
\end{align*}
where $A^\ast$ is the adjoint of $A$. The term $\langle (A+A^\ast)p,h\rangle $ is clearly linear in $h$. The last term is quadratic in $h$ and thus satisfies $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{| \langle Ah,h \rangle |}{||h||}=0$. Therefore, this is a 3-term expansion. Thus
\begin{equation}
    (Dg)_p(h)=\langle (A+A^\ast)p, h\rangle. 
\end{equation}
By the above coordinate-free description of the gradient this shows
\begin{equation}
\nabla g(p)=(A+A^\ast)p.
\end{equation}
The assumption that the matrix $A$ is symmetric just means that $A^\ast=A$. Thus $\nabla g(p)=2Ap$.

Note that I also used the coordinate-free description of the adjoint of a linear map $A$. The adjoint $A^\ast$ of $A$ is defined to be the unique linear map so that
\begin{equation}
 \langle Av,w \rangle =\langle v,A^\ast w \rangle
\end{equation}
holds for all $v,w \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

I hope this helps you to see that once you know the coordinate-free definitions, working without reference to coordinates is much simpler than writing out everything very explicitly in coordinates.

Comment: Notice that in the OP the $A^{ij}$'s are not the entries of a matrix but matrices, and that the domain of the "multiple" quadratic form is $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, not $\mathbb{R}^n$. This of course does not make the problem any more complicated that the case you are discussing, just a little more tedious.

Comment: Okay I didn‘t pay attention to that. But it makes no difference as you can collect all these matrices into one matrix and all vectors into one vector (of course of bigger dimension), i.e. the problem can be reduced to the case of one matrix.